# Moving custom built (from source) Android emulator to another host

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've done a bit of research on this but haven't turned up anything that explains what I am attempting to do. I have successfully built the Android Source (4.2.2) on a Ubuntu machine. It was a generic build (lunch 1). The emulator works just fine (Launches when I execute 'emulator' at the command prompt). I now need to move this emulator to another host. What is the best way to pack this thing up and move it? I can't just install the SDK on the other machine and download an emulator. The idea is that the emulator built on the original machine will be custom and therefore I need to figure out how to transfer it to another machine. Thanks!

Comment: So are you running the Android OS ontop of your ubuntu machine? Did you create your own version of Android? I am confused at what you are looking to do?

Comment: I'm working on some research that requires me to make some slight modifications to the actual Android framework to get it to behave differently. Those changes are reflected in the emulator when I run it. That all works fine. I need to now move this emulator to another machine and have it run there. I would prefer not to copy the source and build on the other machine.

Comment: Essentially, I'm just looking for a way to copy the emulator over to another machine and run it. It seems like there are a lot of files created in the out/target/product/generic folder and I'm not sure what the other machine will need. The other machine will have Java SDK and the Android SDK installed. When all is said and done I need to have my custom emulator (that I've built from modified Android source code) running on this second machine.

Comment: i don't have an exceptionally clear answer for you, but i suggest seeing if your output of your compiled source looks like anything in the "platforms"  and "system-images" folders in the Android-SDK installation.

Comment: I took a look in there but there is about 8GBs of files and folders in there. Most notably are system.img, userdata.img, userdata-qemu.img, ramdisk.img. Do you know which files are necessary to boot the emulator?

Comment: If you were to look at the AVD manager/tool you would see that depending upon the "platform" (android-api, probably what you built from source), there is a "system image" which is basically ARM or intel atom x86. I know x86 is not supported for older android versions, so if you slip your alternated android-api into the platforms folder, you may be able to start one via that then.